# How to write on process.stdin with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with nodejs when trying to write to stdin of a process I have spawned with this spawn function of child_process

```js
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
class Barotrauma {
  static instance = null;
  server = null;

  constructor() {
    this.server = spawn(
      "F:\\dev\\barotrauma\\steamcmd\\steamapps\\common\\Barotrauma Dedicated Server\\DedicatedServer.exe",
      {
        stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr],
      }
    );
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (Barotrauma.instance === null) {
      Barotrauma.instance = new Barotrauma();
    } else {
      return Barotrauma.instance;
    }
  }

  sendCommand(command) {
    //this.server.stdout.write(`${command}\n`)
    // this is a test to get an output on command execution to see if it works
    process.stdin.write("help\n");
  }
}

module.exports = Barotrauma;
```

So, this snippet of code is for starting a game server then send command to it on socket events (the socket call sendCommand function)

if I try to write commands in the console it works fine, but if I try to execute the sendCommand function it crash with error :

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at ReadStream.Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:795:11)
    at ReadStream.Socket._write (node:net:807:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at ReadStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Barotrauma.sendCommand (F:\dev\barotrauma\serverManager.js:26:19)
    at handleReward (F:\dev\barotrauma\handler.js:4:28)
    at WebSocket.connection.onmessage (F:\dev\barotrauma\index.js:26:5)
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4047,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

The crash seems to originate from the process.stin.write function.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `process` is your node script but `this.server` is the process you started. So what you really want is not to write to your own script's stdin but `this.server.stdin.write()`

Comment: Ah. Also, `stdout` is the process's stdout, not it's stdin. You **read** from stdout but write to **stdin**. So you don't want to do `this.server.stdout.write()` (write is not a method available to ReadableStream), what you want is `this.server.stdin.write()`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to [options.stdio](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio).

Without further depth into the full context it's hard to say what's exactly going on, but the following might work as you'd expect:

If you really need the parent and children fds to be connected you could use `pipe` for the `stdio` option and have data be propagated between the two processes.

The following snippet (reduced to minimize noise) should do the trick:

```js
class Barotrauma {
  server = null;

  constructor() {
    // Default `stdio` option is `pipe` for fds 0, 1 and 2 (stdio, stdout and stderr)
    this.server = spawn(
      "F:\\dev\\barotrauma\\steamcmd\\steamapps\\common\\Barotrauma Dedicated Server\\DedicatedServer.exe"
    );

    // Catches incoming messages from child, if necessary
    this.server.stdout.on('data', (d) => {
      console.log(`Message from child: '${d}'`)
    })
  }

  sendCommand(cmd) {
    // Sends messages to child
    this.server.stdin.write(`${cmd}\n`);
  }
}
```

Given you're in a Windows environment, mind you might want to use `overlapped` instead of `pipe` if you need async I/O to communicate with that application. For more info, refer to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o).